# Wordpress customizer strange behaviour

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a panel in the customizer for my theme and it has a stange behaviour.

```
// Color scheme
$wp_customize->add_section('theme_color_scheme', array(
    'title' => __('Theme 1 Color Scheme', 'theme_1'),
    'description' => sprintf(__('Change color scheme of your site', 'theme_1')),
    'priority' => 130
    ));
    // colors
    $wp_customize->add_setting('theme_color', array(
        'default' => _x('samon', 'theme_1'),
        'type' => 'theme_mod'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('theme_color', array(
        'label' => __('Text Color', 'theme_1'),
        'section' => 'theme_color_scheme',
        'type' => 'radio',
        'choices' => array(
                    'samon' => 'Samon',
                    'green' => 'Green',
                    'blue' => 'Blue'
                    ),
        'priority' => 3
    ));
```

First, it doesn't return the default value. None of the options are checked. then, when i try to get the value, it returns blue.

```
$color = get_theme_mod('theme_color_scheme','samon');
echo $color;
```

Even when i change the values it returns blue. Dont know if its a cache problem or a wordpress issue. Sorry if im not making myself clear enough.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found it. turns out it was me who was making the strange behaviour. I was calling it the wrong way. Just changed this ->

```
$color = get_theme_mod('theme_color_scheme','samon');
```

to this ->

```
$color = get_theme_mod('theme_color','samon');
```

Now its working perfectly.
tks again